# Auto preset response in javascript.

Tags: javascript, chat

This is what I am trying to achieve:

When a user types in the input field, the users input data will be displayed above the input box whilst a preset message is displayed under the users message. (like a very simple robot chat)

The sample I am trying complete is:

- The user types in and submits an input of `hello`.
- Then a preset message of `Hello` is returned under the users input if the users input value is equal to `hello`.

You see how its like a robot chat?

Below is the code that I have, and it obviously is not working.

```
<script>
  function submit(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('user').value;
    document.getElementById('userMsg').innerHTML = userInput;
    var userMsg = document.getElementById('userMsg').value;
    if ( userMsg === "hello" )
    {  
      document.getElementById('computerMsg').innerHTML = "Hello";
    }
  }
</script>
<p id="userMsg"></p>
<p id="computerMsg"></p>
<input type="text" id="user" />
<button onclick="submit();" href="javascript:;">Submit</button>
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some simple errors and redundant code in there - cleaned up a little.

```
<script>
    function submit() {
        var userMsg = document.getElementById('user').value;
        if ( userMsg === "hello" ) {  
            document.getElementById('computerMsg').innerHTML = "Hello";
        }
    }
</script>

<p id="userMsg"></p>
<p id="computerMsg"></p>
<input type="text" id="user" />
<button onclick="submit();" href="javascript:;">Submit</button>
```